# Cannot find why this query does not work properly in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, database

I am making a course registration system in asp.net. Now i am building a page that shows the transcript of the student, i.e. all the courses he/she has taken. To do this, i use two table: courses table which keeps the records of all courses, and registration table where i keep the records of all registrations. I click a link button called lbShowTranscript which redirects me to StudenGetTranscript page. I have a gridview in that newly redirected page to show transcript, bu it gives no results, it is always empty. Here is the code:

```
public partial class StudentGetTranscript : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int getid = MyGlobals.student.getID();
    }
}




 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="CourseCode,CourseNumber,Term,StudentID" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CourseCode" HeaderText="CourseCode" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="CourseCode" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CourseNumber" HeaderText="CourseNumber" 
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CourseNumber" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Term" HeaderText="Term" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="Term" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentID" HeaderText="StudentID" ReadOnly="True" 
            SortExpression="StudentID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Grade" HeaderText="Grade" SortExpression="Grade" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CourseName" HeaderText="CourseName" 
            SortExpression="CourseName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CRN" HeaderText="CRN" SortExpression="CRN" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Credit" HeaderText="Credit" 
            SortExpression="Credit" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT RegisterTable.CourseCode, RegisterTable.CourseNumber, RegisterTable.Term, RegisterTable.StudentID, RegisterTable.Grade, CourseTable.CourseName, CourseTable.CRN, CourseTable.Credit FROM RegisterTable INNER JOIN CourseTable ON RegisterTable.CourseCode = CourseTable.CourseCode WHERE (RegisterTable.StudentID = @getid)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="getid" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: Does the query work standalone?  Outside your code?

Comment: When i write no "where" clause it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your page load, you need to set the select parameter value:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["getid"].DefaultValue = getid;
```

Another way to set the value is:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("getid", getid);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code does nothing:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int getid = MyGlobals.student.getID();
}
```

As soon as the function ends, getid disappears.  You need to shove that value into your select parameter.

Comment: But when i debug i see that it returns the current user ID

Comment: oh ok what and how can i do that